# Labeling Core Plot Axis with Units

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

I would like to know how would I go about appending units to Core Plot axes that are dynamic as shown below. Unfortunately, this isn't as easy as looping through the labels and appending text (I believe due to layer manipulation and rendering). Would anyone know how to go about this?

```
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.plotSpace1.xRange.minLimitDouble);//Where the Y Axis meets the X axis
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(200.0);//Interval for X Axis
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
//    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNone;
//    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
//    x.majorTickLength = 12.0;
//    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
//    x.minorTickLength = 8.0;
    x.title = cYards;
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 25.0;
    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];


    // Label y with an automatic labeling policy.
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 11;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(100.0);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.plotSpace1.xRange.minLimitDouble);
    y.title = cInches;
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
    y.titleOffset = 30.0;


    // Label y2 with an equal division labeling policy.
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];

    CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.plotSpace = self.plotSpace2;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.plotSpace1.xRange.maxLimitDouble);//Where the Y Axis meets the X axis
    y2.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 8;

    y2.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(200.0);
    y2.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    y2.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    y2.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y2.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y2.title= cFps;
    y2.titleTextStyle = axisTitleTextStyle;
    y2.titleOffset = 30.0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `NSNumberFormatter`, set the `positiveSuffix` and/or `negativeSuffix`, and set it to the axis `labelFormatter`.